# sub-interface on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking

I would like to add a subinterface on ens192. I don't have a problem setting and using with 2nd or 3rd IP on the same interface. When I am trying to set a subinterface validation has passed on the Netplan file but the subinterface does not appear.
I do not want to use VLANs.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
    ens192:1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 172.16.1.1/24
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
  vlans:
    ens192.1:
      id:1
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 172.16.1.1/24
```